# PnP.PowerShell : "Add-PnPSiteTemplate" command not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, site-template, sharepoint-onlineapp

I want to execute **Add-PnPSiteTemplate** command but am not sure with property '**SiteTemplate**' and '**TenantTemplate**'. Which values are to be passed as parameters.

Please assist how to execute this command successfully.

**My requirement is:** add Site Template to template 'from your Organization' section of SharePoint site.

Appreciate for help and guidance in advance. Thanks!

Comment: You need to create site design script JSON & then add it using `Add-SPOSiteDesign` command. Check [this](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/04/11/site-templates-are-coming-to-sharepoint-online/) & [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview). let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSanap for your assitance!

Actually I used Add-SPOSiteDesign and it worked but using this how to get replicate of existing SitePages. Because our original requirement is create replica(template) of SitePages of existing site. 

Site Page has OOTB webpart like QuickLinks, Document Lib, Weather webpart only.

Comment: Hi @Ganesh, please assist here if you have a solution for this.